# Function not working anymore when executed from own package

Tags: r, functional-programming, environment-variables, package, environment

Hope you can give me a quick help:

I have a `function` that works perfect as run in the `global envir`. When I eval the `function` from my own `package` it gives me an error. I can't figure out what the problem is. Seem so random to me.

```
catTableFun(aaa,grouped_by = "varNameAsString",preview=T) #from global envir works as expected

elricoFuns::catTableFun(aaa,grouped_by = "varNameAsString",preview=T) # identical function run from package gives the following error
```

Error:

```
#Error in get(grouped_by) : object 'varNameAsString' not found
```

Its such a construct causing the error. But why?

```
setDT(x)
gnLevels <- x[,get(grouped_by),drop=F]
```

I'm sorry I cant give you some rep example and this is a broad question, but I hope someone has encountered a similar phenomenon or has an educated guess about it.

Comment: You'll probably have to provide the definition of `catTableFun` to get a helpful answer.

Comment: try replacing with `gnLevels <- x[, grouped_by, with = F]`

Comment: from `data.table` manual: "drop - Never used by data.table. Do not use. ..."

Comment: @minem i just dont get why the code works in global envir but not from called from package.